# TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'request'

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-forms, djangorestframework

Cuando trato de hacer uso del método **dispatch** de las vistas basadas en clases, me dice que hace falta pasarle la request (es error que aparece es el titulo de la publicación). Se lo estoy pasando pero no me funciona, ¿Qué no estoy viendo? (Django 3.2).

Views

```
from django.utils.decorators import method_decorator
from django.views.decorators.cache import never_cache
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_protect
from django.views.generic.edit import FormView
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
from django.contrib.auth import login

from .forms import FormularioLogin
# Create your views here.

class Login(FormView):
    template_name = 'login.html'
    form_class = FormularioLogin
    success_url = reverse_lazy('index')
    
    @method_decorator(csrf_protect)
    @method_decorator(never_cache)
    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if request.user.is_authenticated:
            return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())
        else:
            return super(Login, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
      
    def form_valid(self, form):
        login(self.request, form.get_user())
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

Forms

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import AuthenticationForm

class FormularioLogin(AuthenticationForm):
    def __init__(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(request, *args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['username'].widget.attrs['class'] = 'form-control'
        self.fields['username'].widget.attrs['placeholder'] = 'Nombre de usuario'
        
        self.fields['password'].widget.attrs['class'] = 'form-control'
        self.fields['password'].widget.attrs['placeholder'] = 'Contraseña'
```

urls

```
from apps.usuario.views import Login

urlpatterns = [
    path('accounts/login/', Login.as_view(), name="login")
]
```

Gracias

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: ¿Por qué no usas la forma `super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)`? (en realidad no creo que esto vaya a resolver el problema, pero es de todas formas la práctica moderna, en vez de pasarle a `super()` la clase y el objeto)

Comment: @Christian No creo que ese sea el problema porque el error menciona que falta un parámetro _posicional_

Comment: Creo que le falta `self`: `super().__init__(request, *args, **kwargs)`

Comment: No uso django, pero basándome en el error y en lo que conozco de la sintaxis python ¿no será que `request` no es un parámetro explícito sino que te viene formando parte de `*args`? Es decir, que deberías declarar `__init__()` solo con los parámetros `self, *args, y **kwargs`, y luego dentro hacer `request = args[0]` si es que necesitas ese valor para algo, y después `super().__init__(request, *args[1:], **kwargs)` Si no, necesitas separar `requests` para otra cosa puedes directamente usar `super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)`

Comment: Hola @abulafia, si no que este es un método heredado de una clase base para las vistas basadas en clases de Django, la definición de este método obligatoriamente pide como parámetro la request (hablo propiamente del método), mientras que su constructor __init__() solo pide la instancia del objeto y unos **kwargs por si se le va a pasar algo más. Pero para este caso no es necesario hacer uso del constructor; por ello el llamado no lo hago por medio de __init__(). Sin embargo si me equivoco, estoy atento a una respuesta. Gracias por tus comentarios.

Comment: @Jhon Creo que tu último comentario es la clave. Dices que el método `dispatch()` requiere el parámetro `request`, pero el método `__init__()` no. En cambio en tu código declaras también el parámetro `request` en `__init__()`, por lo que es aplicable lo que yo decía en mi anterior comentario. Debes quitar ese parámetro e invocar `super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)`

Answer (score 0):

El error no estaba en el dispatch como yo pensaba (La consola me marcaba ahí el error). Analizando lo copiado en el código, el error estaba en el forms en su clase `FormularioLogin`(....), *pues le estaba pasando **request** en el constructor de este formulario* y resulta que este constructor no lleva el request, tampoco lo lleva la clase padre.

```
class FormularioLogin(AuthenticationForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```